# Cannot see thumbnail on my blog link posted on Facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook

Cannot see thumbnail on my blog link posted on Facebook

I tried using FB developer tools and I see only a ugly gray generic image from my link, not a proper thumbnail.
I don't know how to solve.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Flnx.sinapsi.org%2Fwordpress%2F2016%2F10%2F07%2Fdentista-di-coccodrilli%2F

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Thumbnail picture exactly what in your og:image, if you don't like it i think that you must change your og:image.